# Ontology for theme of a text

Tags: rdf, ontology

I'm looking for an ontology that describes the theme of a text (eg. "finance", "leisure"). A text can have multiple themes. Preferably the ontology would also have room to store a match percentage:

```
{
    "theme": "finance",
    "match": "96.2%"
}
```

I looked at [`foaf:theme`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_theme) but it appears to be deprecated and doesn't allow any extra properties.

Answer (score 1):

- For a straight theme, use `<doc> dc:subject "foo"`
- To add confidence, you can use RDF*:

  - `<< <doc> dc:subject "foo" >> my:confidence 0.962`

But maybe RDF* is an overkill.

- You can use the NIF (NLP Interchange Format) ontology. Use `its:taIdentRef` to point to the theme (has to be a URL), and I think `its:taIdentConf` is for the confidence
- Another option is to use the Web Annotation ontology. Put the doc URL in `oa:hasTarget`, the theme in `oa:hasBody` and the confidence in . This is how Ontotext's TAG works (disclaimer: I work for them)